# Why is a geometric theory called “geometric”?

Tags: logic, category-theory, terminology, topos-theory, locales

In topos theory, the notion of “being geometric” often comes up. Some examples are: [geometric morphisms](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+morphism), geometric logic, and [geometric theories](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric+theory). For instance, here's a quote from Steve Vickers' [Locales and Toposes as Spaces](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/%7Esjv/LocTopSpaces.pdf):

> ... the logic is not at all ordinary classical logic. It is an infinitary
> positive logic known as *geometric* logic.

I have a vague intuition on this notion of geometricity: in locale theory one sees open sets as *observable* properties, and my understanding of geometricity is that when we [categorify](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/vertical+categorification) from opens to sheaves, the notion of observability generalises to geometricity. In this context, “geometric morphisms” make sense as they respect the geometric structure as a continuous function respects the observability structure. However, I don't quite understand the use of the adjective “geometric” for this.

How do I connect the intuition of observability with the notion of geometricity? If this approach doesn't make much sense, what is a good way to think about geometricity?

---

PS: I am aware that the paper of Vickers I linked to essentially aims to explain the spatial intuition in detail. However, it seems to take for granted the notion of being “geometric” without a familiarity with which I find hard to follow the paper.

Comment: Why  look to grammar, but not to content? The reference clears up what is being discussed.

Comment: Geometric logic is precisely the fragment of logic preserved by (the inverse image part of) geometric morphisms. Geometric morphisms are contrasted with _logical_ morphisms, which preserve all higher order logic.

Comment: I think @ZhenLin hits the nail on the head, pushing the question back one step to "why are geometric morphisms called geometric?". Here the answer is clear: geometric morphisms are the functors between toposes which generalize continuous maps of topological spaces, in the sense that a geometric morphism between locales is precisely a morphism of locales, and a morphism of spatial locales corresponds precisely to a continuous map of the corresponding topological spaces.

Comment: So maybe it might help intuition to substitute "topological" for "geometric". In the end, this "observability" business has always looked to me like a song and dance about how to think about topological spaces, starting right from the open sets. It does seem to be a helpful way to think for computational applications.

Comment: Just a note that the reason why “geometric” was chosen rather than “topological” is that toposes originated in algebraic geometry, whereas locale theory came later.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone. @KevinArlin, your explanation combined with all the other comments constitutes an answer to my question. Would someone like to add this as an answer?

Comment: This question has already been answered, but let me mention [a very nice exposition of Blass](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/eatcs.pdf).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To summarize the comments: geometric logic constitutes the logic, models of whose theories are preserved by geometric *morphisms* between topoi. Geometric morphisms are those appropriate to toposes viewed as generalized spaces, for instance, identifying the topos of sheaves on a topological space, or on a locale, with the space itself. Historically, toposes were first introduced by Grothendieck's school to model generalized *algebro-geometric* spaces, which explains why these morphisms are called geometric, rather than topological.